# Can I make Maven refuse to build when there are version conflicts?

Tags: java, maven

The tile pretty much says it all.

I often deal with a project which depends on libraries `A` and `B`,

where `A` wants to pull in `C version 1.0.0` and `B` wants to pull in `C version 1.5.6`.

Maven's default behavior seems to be that `mvn package` succeeds, including one or the other version of `C` on the classpath.

I would like to specify in my `pom.xml` that maven should refuse to build the project until one of the two `C` dependencies has been excluded.

Can this be done without first writing a new plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maven enforcer plugin should be able to check that, see [Dependency Convergence here](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html)